# How to include a controller method's view as a part of another controller view in Laravel PHP Framework

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Halo here is my need;
i want to include different view as apart of different view in laravel php frame work.

```
class DashboardController extends BaseController {
  public function comments( $level_1=''){

   // process data according to $lavel_1

    return View::make('dashboard.comments', $array_of_all_comments);
  }

public function replys( $level_2=''){

   // process data according to $lavel_1
  return View::make('dashboard.replys', $array_of_all_replys);
 }
```

these both data can now accessed from

```
www.abc.com/dashboard/comments
www.abc.com/dashboard/replys
```

And in my view what i need is to generate replys according to the comments id ($lavel_2)

```
// dashboard/comments.blade.php
 @extends('layout.main')
 @section('content')

 @foreach($array_of_all_comments as $comment)
   comment {{ $comment->data }},

//here is what i need to load reply according to the current data;
//need to do something like this below

 @include('dashboard.replys', $comment->lavel_2) //<--just for demo
  .................
 @stop
```

and in replys also got

```
@extends('layout.main')
 @section('content')
  // dashboard/replys.blade.php
    @foreach($array_of_all_replys as $reply)
       You got a reply {{ $reply->data }},
         ...........
  @stop
```

is there any way i can achieve this on laravel 4?

Please help me i wanted to load both comments and replays in one go and later need to access them individually via ajax also

please help me thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

halo i found the solution here

all we need is to use `App::make('DashboardController')->reply();`
 and remove all `@extends` and `@sections` from including view file

the change are like this

```
 // dashboard/comments.blade.php
 @extends('layout.main')
 @section('content')

 @foreach($array_of_all_comments as $comment)
   comment {{ $comment->data }},
  //<-- here is the hack to include them 
{{-- */echo App::make('DashboardController')->reply($comment->lavel_2);/* --}}
  .................
 @stop
 .............
```

and in replys is now changed to

```
  // dashboard/replys.blade.php
    @foreach($array_of_all_replys as $reply)
       You got a reply {{ $reply->data }},
         ...........
  @endforeach
   -------------
```

thanks

Comment: I can't emphasise how hacky and bad-practice this is. You're exploiting the parsing engine of the Blade tag to do HMVC, something which Laravel is designed to not need (for the most part) in a view. Creating a new Controller in a view (and creating `n` new Controllers, where `n` is the size of `$array_of_all_comments) is something that should never be in any view, for any reason

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to rework your views and normalise your data. Comments and replies are (probably) the same.

If you make a Comment model which belongsTo "parent" (another Comment model) and hasMany "children" (many Comment models), then simply set `parent_id` to 0 for a top-level Comment, and set it to the ID of another Comment to make it a Reply.

Then your Blade views do something like:

```
comments.blade.php

@foreach ($comments AS $comment)
    @include( 'comment', [ 'comment' => $comment ] )
@endforeach
```

---

```
comment.blade.php

<div>
    <p>{{{ $comment->message }}}</p>
    @if( $comment->children->count() )
        <ul>
            @foreach( $comment->children AS $comment )
               <li>
                   @include( 'comment', [ 'comment' => $comment ] )
               </li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    @endif
</div>
```